# Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix) in C#

Tags: c#

I have this function in a Java program.

```
private static byte[] converToByte(String s)
    {
        byte[] output = new byte[s.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2, j++)
        {
            output[j] = (byte)(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I am trying to create the same thing with C# but I'm having troubles. I tried this:

```
output[j] = (byte)(Int16.Parse(str.Substring(i, i + 2)));
```

But after a couple of iterations I got a System.OverflowException, what would be the instruction in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `Convert.ToByte(string, int)`. (It's not clear why you were looking at `Int16.Parse` in this case... that doesn't map to either "parsing a single byte" or "the equivalent of `Integer.parseInt`.)

Comment: Removing `[java]` as it won't be in the answer, just referred to in the question.

Comment: @axy108 Did you find an answer to this?  I am porting some java code to c# with the same problem (Using blowfish decryption)

Comment: `Int16.Parse` isn't going to parse a hex number by default -- You either have to pass in `NumberStyles.HexNumber` (ideally into `Byte.Parse`), or just use `Convert.ToByte` with `16` as the value for the `radix` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static sbyte[] converToByte(string s)
{
    sbyte[] output = new sbyte[s.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2, j++)
    {
        output[j] = (sbyte)(Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong data type in your line:

```
output[j] = (byte)(Int16.Parse(str.Substring(i, i + 2)));

Short Name   .NET Class Type    Width Range (bits) 
byte  Byte   Unsigned   integer   8    0 to 255
short Int16  Signed     integer   16   -32,768 to 32,767
```

You are getting an overflow exception because an Int16 (short) is far to big to fit into a byte.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with tihs problem myself I realised the real problem is that Java's substring method is:

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

While C#'s implementation takes:

```
substring(int beginIndex, int length)
```

This means in the C# the same code is grabbing larger chunks of bytes causing an overflow.

@Dave Doknjas was on the right track but you can still convert to a byte with the new smaller chunk size.

```
output[j] = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(i, i + 2), 16);
```